# How to find element and append new element using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple section with video player now I would like to append a new created element, so here is my solution,

```
button.addeventlistener('click', function(){
        incrementID++;
        var newID ='player' + incrementID;
        var youtubeBlock = document.createElement('div');
        youtubeBlock.id =newID;
       
       $(this).parent().find(".loveplayer video").appendChild(youtubeBlock) 

)}
```

unfortunately, this is not appending the new div

What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you share `html` also?

Comment: You should use youtubeBlock.setAttribute('id', newID) to add id attribute to your youtubeBlock element

Comment: @idhruv, `youtubeBlock.id =newID;` is also valid syntax as well.

Comment: .find() function expects a 'selector' or an 'element'. Refer: https://api.jquery.com/find/#find-selector

Comment: @idhruv so how do I solve my problem?

Comment: Also the ending braces are jumbled. 
It should ideally first close the curly braces and then the round braces.

Comment: when i do this `$(this).parent().find(".loveplayer video").hide()` it find the element and hide it , why it does not append?

Comment: @TheDeadMan it would be easier to solve if you can also add the HTML code.

Comment: @idhruv there is too much html code to share, the question is why I am able to hide it but I cant append new element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216623/discussion-between-idhruv-and-the-dead-man).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var element = $(this).parent().find('.loveplayer video');
element.append(youtubeBlock);
```

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/find/) of .find():

Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .find() method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Alternatively, you may access the parent element in a different way and try this out:

```
button.on("click", () => {
  incrementID++;
  var newID = 'player' + incrementID;
  var youtubeBlock = $(`<div id="${newID}">HEY</div>`);
  $("#parentElementID").append(youtubeBlock)
});
```

Refer: https://jsfiddle.net/idhruvs/82v1ac9p/4/

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: element.appendChild is not a function`

Comment: check the console.log(element) looks like this : https://ibb.co/YRVpfJR  just another id name

Comment: it shoudl be element.append(youtubeBlock) instead of element.appendChild(youtubeBlock).
appendChild is a DOM API, but since find() returns a JQuery object it will have an append method available rather than appendChild.

Just edited my answer

Comment: you don't need the `clone` method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the question but if so I think I have a solution.

```js
$(".video-button").on("click", () => {
    let parent = $(".video-button").parents(".video-player");
  let newElement = $("<div>").addClass("newElement").text("newElement");
  
  parent.append(newElement);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body {
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.video-player {
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  position:relative;
}

.video {
  background:#222;
  height:400px;
  width:600px;
}

.video-button {
   height:50px; 
   width:200px;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:20px;
   left:20px;
   cursor:pointer;
   background:green;
}

.newElement {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:20px;
  right:20px;
  background:blue;
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-player">
  <div class="video"></div>
  <div class="video-button">Add</div>
</div>
```